# Is it bad practice to apply <context:component-scan> to every package in a Spring MVC (3.0) app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it ok to do this since it will include all packages and subpackages in the app for component scanning?

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="rootpackage" />
```

Or is there a reason to be selective about which packages to scan?

e.g.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="rootpackage.abc" />
<context:component-scan base-package="rootpackage.def" />
<!--<context:component-scan base-package="rootpackage.ghi" /> --> Omit? Why?
```

Why would you ever omit packages from the scan?

Comment: You can filter the classes which are scanned. See the approach in [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609846/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's bad practice.

If components can appear in any package, readers of your sourcebase need to search every class for Spring annotations, instead of just looking in, say, a "components" package and a "controllers" package.

Plus, you shouldn't have Spring components scattered around your package structure. Group your classes into meaningful packages and only expose those.

Comment: if they use SpringSource ToolSuite, the Spring Explorer will show them all Spring Components in the scanned packages.

Answer (score 1):

It make sense to be selective if you have several configs. For instance `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, `applicationContext-common-business.xml`, `applicationContext-security.xml` etc