# Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 transaction management error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm kinda new with the Spring's transaction management. I think I'm missing some configuration but I can't deal with it.

The error is that I'm getting `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role` exception.

I'm using Spring Data for my DAO. Also, I know about setting the fetchType to Eager but this is what I'm trying to avoid.

DAO:

```
public interface CourseDao extends CrudRepository<CourseEntity, Long> {
    CourseEntity findByName(String name);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CourseMaterialSearchService {
    private final CourseDao courseDao;
    private final CourseMaterialEntityTransformer courseMaterialEntityTransformer;

    @Autowired
    public CourseMaterialSearchService(CourseDao courseDao, CourseMaterialEntityTransformer courseMaterialEntityTransformer) {
        super();
        this.courseDao = courseDao;
        this.courseMaterialEntityTransformer = courseMaterialEntityTransformer;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<CourseMaterial> findMaterialsFor(final Long courseId) {
        final CourseEntity entity = courseDao.findOne(courseId);
        final List<CourseMaterialEntity> materials = entity.getCourseMaterialEntityList();
        return courseMaterialEntityTransformer.transformEntities(materials);
    }
}
```

And my application-context.xml is (of course this is just the relevant part):

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="example" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="exampleDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.example.**.repository" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I call the `findMaterialsFor` method in `CourseMaterialSearchService`, the exception occurs. How should I solve this?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you guys.

Stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.example.course.repository.domain.CourseEntity.courseMaterialEntityList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
com.example.example.course.service.transform.CourseMaterialEntityTransformer.transformEntities(CourseMaterialEntityTransformer.java:15)
com.example.example.course.service.CourseMaterialSearchService.findMaterialsFor(CourseMaterialSearchService.java:29)
```

CourseMaterialEntityTransformer:

```
public class CourseMaterialEntityTransformer {
        public List<CourseMaterial> transformEntities(final Iterable<CourseMaterialEntity> entities) {
            final List<CourseMaterial> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final CourseMaterialEntity entity : entities) {
                result.add(transformEntity(entity));
            }
            return result;
        }

    public CourseMaterial transformEntity(final CourseMaterialEntity entity) {
        final CourseMaterial result = new CourseMaterial();
        result.setId(entity.getId());
        result.setName(entity.getName());
        result.setCourseName(entity.getCourseEntity().getName());
        result.setCurrentFileName(entity.getCurrentFileName());
        result.setOriginalFileName(entity.getOriginalFileName());
        result.setCategory(entity.getMaterialCategoryEntity().getName());
        result.setUploader(entity.getUserEntity().getName());
        return result;
    }
}
```

`com.example.example.course.service.transform.CourseMaterialEntityTransformer.transformEntities(CourseMaterialEntityTransformer.java:15)`:

```
for (final CourseMaterialEntity entity : entities) {
```

CourseEntity:

```
@Entity(name = "courses")
public class CourseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "courseEntity")
    private List<CourseMaterialEntity> courseMaterialEntityList;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<CourseMaterialEntity> getCourseMaterialEntityList() {
        return courseMaterialEntityList;
    }

    public void setCourseMaterialEntityList(final List<CourseMaterialEntity> courseMaterialEntityList) {
        this.courseMaterialEntityList = courseMaterialEntityList;
    }

}
```

Comment: My question is updated.

Comment: plz post the domain object as well

Comment: WIld guess you are scanning for components twice. Your `application-context.xml` as a `<context:component-scan />` as well as your `[servlet]-servlet.xml`, scanning both the `@Service` leading to a non transactional one used in your controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum thats right. Thank you. I would not think about that at all. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring applies transactions using AOP. AOP on beans is only applied to beans in the same application context.

You have a `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your `application-context.xml`, which is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. This file contains a `<context:component-scan />` which detects the `@Service`.

However if you also have the same `<context:component-scan />` in the file loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`, or at least if the same `@Service` is detected it results in another instance of this service which will not have AOP applied.

As a general rule-of-thumb you want to load everything BUT `@Controllers` in your `ContextLoaderListener` and only web related things (view resolvers, `@Controllers`) in your `DispatcherServlet`.

See [context depended scan-component filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609846/context-depended-scan-component-filter).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a lazy-loaded attribute outside of a transaction. The object then has no connection with the EntityManager (database), since it's outside of a transaction, and thus cannot go fetch the lazy-loaded attribute.

Comment: ehm, okay, but how to solve it? If I call entity.getCourseMaterialEntityList().size() in the findMaterialsFor method, it should work right?

Comment: He have `@Transactional` on top of method so it should be in `@Transactional` scope.

Comment: Only if the transaction manager is properly set up to handle the annotation. The error message is what it is, and that is the explanation I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default Collections are lazy-loaded . You can replace below your code :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "courseEntity")
private List<CourseMaterialEntity> courseMaterialEntityList;
```

With :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "courseEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CourseMaterialEntity> courseMaterialEntityList;
```

Comment: I don't want to fetch it eagerly, thats what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "courseEntity")` to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "courseEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

The default fetch type is lazy so when you try and access the collection it hasn't been loaded from the database.

Comment: I don't want to fetch eagerly.

Comment: It is not necessarily to fetch eagerly. Problem is in transaction that he tries to load entities out of transaction somehow.

Comment: what does `CourseMaterialEntity` look like?